# Timer in button c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have a button that I want timer in it, say for 30 sec and when it elapsed the button will be enable. Like the buttons to download files.

1)Is it OK if in the Page_Load() I will write the timer and start it?
2)How I make it to change on time in the button.text?
3)How to make that when in elapsed the button will be enable?

Thanks,
OR

Comment: How about trying? Get a compiler and test it.

Comment: I would do it in the Loaded event instead of Load.

Comment: This is going to have to be done in JavaScript because the page will be rendered to the client before the timer goes off. When it goes off, there's no connection to the client.

Comment: I dont now how to change the text online and how to call a function when it elapsed..

Answer (score 1):

Is this a question about webforms? Then you can't use a .NET timer. But you can use a JavaScript timer.

Somewhere near the bottom of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var button = document.getElementById("the_button_id");
        button.disabled = true;
        setTimeout(function() {
            button.disabled = false;
        }, 30000);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: I was watching this question, may I ask why you set the button.disabled to true in the javascript? Would you not set the button to be disabled in the c# code and only enable it in the javascript code?

Comment: You wouldn't, because you can't guarantee that the end user has JavaScript enabled. If scripts are blocked, the button would never become enabled, unless the script is also where you disable the button in the first place.